# ZeroMQ bidirectional async communication with subprocesses

Tags: python, sockets, ipc, zeromq

I have a server process which receives requests from a web clients. 
The server has to call an external worker process ( another .py ) which streams data to the server and the server streams back to the client.

The server has to monitor these worker processes and send messages to them ( basically kill them or send messages to control which kind of data gets streamed ). These messages are asynchronous ( e.g. depend on the web client )

I thought in using ZeroMQ sockets over an `ipc://`-transport-class , but the call for `socket.recv()` method is blocking.

Should I use two sockets ( one for streaming data to the server and another to receive control messages from server )?

Comment: You can use a [Poller](http://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.html#poller) to implement non-blocking code.

Answer (score 2):

### Using a separate socket for signalling and messaging is always better

While a `Poller`-instance will help a bit, the cardinal step is to use separate socket for signalling and another one for data-streaming. Always. The point is, that in such setup, both the `Poller.poll()` and the event-loop can remain socket-specific and spent not more than a predefined amount of time, during a real-time controlled code-execution.

So, do not hesitate to setup a bit richer signalling/messaging infrastructure as an environment where you will only enjoy the increased simplicity of control, separation of concerns and clarity of intents.

ZeroMQ is an excellent tool for doing this - including per-socket IO-thread affinity, so indeed a fine-grain performance tuning is available at your fingertips.

Comment: +1 for the using two separate sockets idea. I also think is the why to go. I was thinking about using plain sockets and a separate thread that handles the messages. 

How can ZeroMQ help me in that? Basically, I don't quite understand your last sentence.

Comment: Once one manages the few trivial ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Behaviour Archetypes, next comes performance. Using ZeroMQ API, one can tweak maximum performance / minimum latency in fine grain manner, one socket having absolute priority ( a private ZeroMQ data-pump IO-thread, while others, low-prio may share other ZeroMQ data-pumping IO-thread-pool --- all still under one high-level API, thus being able to setup and tweak all the circus from the same, high-level, language pre-API ZeroMQ socket abstraction. No one would like to cover all that at low-level resources handling trial/errors)

Answer (score 0):

I think if figured out a solution, but I don't know if there is a better (more efficient, safer, ...) way of doing this.
The `client` makes a request to the `server`, which spawns `N` processes `worker` to attend the request.

This is the relevant excerpt from `worker.py`:

```
for i in range(start_counter,10):
    # Check if there is any message from server
    while True:
        try:
            msg = worker.recv(zmq.DONTWAIT)
            print("Received {} from server".format(msg))
        except zmq.Again:
            break

    # Send data to server
    worker.send(b"Message {} from {}".format(i, worker_id))

    # Take some sleep
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.3, 1.1))
```

In this way, the `worker` a) does not need a separate socket and b) does not need a separate thread to process messages from `server`.

In the real implementation, `worker` must stream 128 byte messages at 100Hz to the `server`, and the `server` must receive lots of this messages (many clients asking requests that need 3-10 `worker` each). 
Will this approach suffer a performance hit if implemented this way?